# Problems with React Redux store passing props to children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

What I am trying to accomplish is to have one "controller" file that renders out all the components to my page.. And I tried implementing redux to pass props to my component childrens but I do not get it to work. Here's my files:

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import store from './js/store.jsx'
import App from './js/App.jsx'

// Assigning the sections
const nav = document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[0];

//Render the components
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
<App />

</Provider>, nav)
```

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Cart from './components/cart/Cart.jsx'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

  render() {
    return <Cart />
  }
}
```

Cart.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {fetchCart} from '../../actions/cartActions'
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


@connect((store) => {

})
export default class Cart extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchCart())
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
         this.state = {

        };

    }

  render() {
    return( <div>

    <div className="cart-scroll-area">
          {/* Bryt ut till egna komponenter */}
          <header className="cart-header"></header>
          <header className="cart-meta">
            <div className="cart-meta-info">
                <div className="cart-timer">Avsluta din order inom<br /><strong>xxxx</strong><br /></div>
                <div className="status ok">
                    för leverans tidigast xxxx
                </div>
            </div>
          </header>
          <section className="cart-section cart-errors"></section>
          <section className="cart-section cart-section-homelist"></section>
          <section className="cart-section cart-section-bag-header"></section>
          <section className="cart-section cart-section-prenumeration"></section>
          <section className="cart-section cart-section-flexbag"></section>
          <section className="cart-section cart-section-recipes"></section>
          <section className="cart-section cart-section-mostbought"></section>
          <section className="cart-section cart-section-accessories"></section>
      </div>
      <div className="cart-scroll-footer">
          <div className="cart-total"></div>
          <div className="cart-total-price"></div>
          <footer className="cart-footer"></footer>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

¨

cartActions.js

```
let restPath = "/ShoppingCart";

export function fetchCart(){
  return {
    type: "FETCH_CART",
    payload: {data:["Event 1", "Event 2"]}
    //payload: axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/events")
  }
}
```

cartReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  cart: [],
  error: null
}

export default function reducer(state=initialState, action=null) {
console.log(action.payload)
  switch (action.type){

    case "FETCH_CART_PENDING" : {
      return {...state, fetching:true}
      break;
    }
    case "FETCH_CART_REJECTED" : {
      return {...state, fetching:false, error:action.payload}
      break;
    }
    case "FETCH_CART_FULFILLED" : {
      return {...state,
        fetching:false,
        fetched:true,
        cart:action.payload.data
      }
      break;
    }
    case "FETCH_CART" : {
      return {...state,
        fetching:false,
        fetched:true,
        cart:action.payload.data
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  return state
}
```

And finally here's my store.jsx

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware'
import reducer from './reducers'

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger())

export default createStore(reducer, middleware)
```

Right now I am getting this.props.dispatch is not a function. And I do not get any props/store containing the `"payload: {data:["Event 1", "Event 2"]}"`

Can anyone help me out? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're usage of `connect` is incorrect. You want to map the state and dispatcher to props for the component. In addition, I would suggest connecting the top-level `App` container and passing props to its children. Try something like this :

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import Cart from './components/cart/Cart.jsx'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {fetchCart} from '../../actions/cartActions'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <Cart
     fetching={this.props.fetching}
     fetched={this.props.fetched}
     cart={this.props.cart}
     error={this.props.error}
     fetchCart={this.props.fetchCart} />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  // These will be passed as props into the component.
  return { 
    fetching: state.fetching,
    fetched: state.fetched,
    cart: state.cart,
    error: state.error
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  // These will be passed as props into the component.
  return {
    fetchCart: () => dispatch(fetchCart()) 
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**Cart.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Cart extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchCart();
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { };
  }

  render() {
    // this.props.fetching, this.props.fetched etc. should exist.
    console.log(this.props);

    return(
     <div>
        <div className="cart-scroll-area">
           {/* Bryt ut till egna komponenter */}
           <header className="cart-header"></header>
           <header className="cart-meta">
              <div className="cart-meta-info">
                 <div className="cart-timer">Avsluta din order inom<br /><strong>xxxx</strong><br /></div>
                 <div className="status ok">
                    för leverans tidigast xxxx
                 </div>
              </div>
           </header>
           <section className="cart-section cart-errors"></section>
           <section className="cart-section cart-section-homelist"></section>
           <section className="cart-section cart-section-bag-header"></section>
           <section className="cart-section cart-section-prenumeration"></section>
           <section className="cart-section cart-section-flexbag"></section>
           <section className="cart-section cart-section-recipes"></section>
           <section className="cart-section cart-section-mostbought"></section>
           <section className="cart-section cart-section-accessories"></section>
        </div>
        <div className="cart-scroll-footer">
           <div className="cart-total"></div>
           <div className="cart-total-price"></div>
           <footer className="cart-footer"></footer>
        </div>
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some key parts when it comes to connecting your app to redux. You need to connect redux to the `react` container you wish to have access to the data. You also need to create a function to `mapStateToProps`, which allows you access the data in the redux store as props. You also will need to create a function called `mapDispatchToProps` to allow you use the `fetchCart` method in your container.

Firstly, you need to import `connect` from `react-redux`.

`import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux'`

To connect the `App` component to `redux` you need to use the redux `connect` method and pass in the two functions you created called `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` and the `App` component as callbacks.

`const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);`

You then put the `ConnectedApp` inside the `Provider` in the ReactDOM.render function.

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp />
</Provider>, nav) 

import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux'    

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    state: state
 })

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({fetchCart: () => dispatch(fetchCart())})

const nav = document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[0];
const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

//Render the components
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp />
</Provider>, nav)
```

To use the `redux-logger` you need to do the following

```
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
const logger = createLogger();
const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, promise, logger);
```

Please note the order in which you pass in `logger` matters. It needs to be passed into `applyMiddleware` as the final argument.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I got my component to be able to call fetchCart now. Do you know how to enable the redux debug/logging in the console?

Comment: @Codehiker see updated answer for how to use the `redux-logger`

Comment: Thanks. I had that in place already. The issue with your suggested code is that it does not run the cartAction redux-action. It seems to only call the cartReducer upon init?

Comment: there is a few differences between how you set up the logger and how it needs to be implemented. Is the logger working now? Where are you calling `fetchCart` in your code?